# User cannot authenticate after signup when object cache enabled

Tags: cache

I've just upgraded to WordPress 3.5.1 and the new `object-cache.php` version 2.0.2 that users some new switch to blog cache functionality.

We had this issue with the previous version of object cache, but i managed to solve it by delete the users keys when doing signup and activation of the blogs. This cleared the cached password from memcache, that for some reason is wrong.

I tried re-implement this, but it does not work. I've put this code in my register page:

```
wp_cache_key_delete("4e76434eea3c9d9cf9cb10bbf3f4a74b92:users:1"); 
wp_cache_delete('users');
```

the hash is my KEY SALT

and again on the activation page I use this

```
wp_cache_key_delete("4e76434eea3c9d9cf9cb10bbf3f4a74b92:users:".$user_id);
wp_cache_delete('users');
```

This should clear the cached users and their password, so auth will happens against the password in the MySQL database.

I added these 2 functions to `object-cache.php` to handle they key deletion

#hack by tonny

```
function wp_cache_key_delete($key) {
    global $wp_object_cache;

      return $wp_object_cache->key_delete($key);
}
```

and this

```
    function key_delete($key) {

            $mc =& $this->get_mc($group);

            $result = $mc->delete($key);

            @ ++$this->stats['delete'];
            $this->group_ops[$group][] = "delete $id";

            if ( false !== $result )
                    unset($this->cache[$key]);

            return $result;
    }
```

Has any of you had similar issues with users not beging able to login when signing up / registering a blog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved The solution was this in the activation script:

```
$blog_real_id = $wpdb->get_var("select blog_id from wp_bp_user_blogs where user_id = ".$user_id." limit 1");

wp_cache_key_delete("1:users:".$user_id);
wp_cache_key_delete($blog_real_id.":users:".$user_id);
```

This clears the cached user info for blog id 1 and the signed up blog ud. For some reason the password hash that is in memcache is wrong. Clearing it before logging in will authenticate aginst mysql insterad of the cached password in memcache.